# how to write the figure name using dot

Tags: graphviz, dot

What I want to ask is that we can draw figures using **dot** but is it possible to give a **name** to that figure and that name comes **below that figure**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is about graphviz, here's how to add a label below the graph:

```
digraph {
    1 -> 2;
    labelloc="b";
    label="Graph label";
}
```

[image: graphviz output]

Comment: Can you tell me how to specify the size of label too

Comment: You can use `labelfontsize` - check out all attributes on http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs